# Apache/Django Install: RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit

Tags: python, django, apache, django-models

I am using Django 1.9 and python 2.7 on centos7

I am getting the following error ONLY when trying to use Apache with Django.

```
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I do NOT get the error using the Django web-server, my application works fine under the Django web-server, but I have read not to use the Django web-server but Apache instead.

I have run into multiple issues trying to get apache to work with django, and have found solutions to all of the preceding issues, but cannot resolve this one.

Here are my installed apps with "`django.contrib.contenttypes`" in the list in this order:

```
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'admin_alerts',
'admin_dq_metrics',
'admin_db_conn',
'admin_file_conn',
'admin_application',
'admin_process',
'admin_src_status_chk',
'admin_scheduler_template',
'export_to_db',
'export_to_file',
'migrate_to_prod',
'migrate_to_stg',
'migrate_to_dev',
'tableau_tde',
'ingest_file',
'ingest_db',
'scheduler',
'dq_entity_cross_ref',
'high_water_column_ref',
'process_control',
'difa_login',
'admin_create_user',
'update_export_ingest_data',
'admin_add_user',
'django.contrib.sites',
```

Thanks...

Comment: Show the code where you get this error.